# Problem in using pyzbar on a shared hosting system

Tags: python, django, zbar

I'm developing a web system with Django 2.0.6 which at one point needs to read an image of a qrcode. So, on my local machine I used pyzbar on my virtualenv to realize such need and it worked perfectly. I ran several tests, and until then it was working perfectly.

So I had the need to host the system on a shared server (I had already performed such a procedure for another web system made with Django 2.0.6), and this time gave an error in the hosting due to the pyzbar library, claiming that the library was not properly installed. I asked the support of the host company to verify the problem and I was told the following: "I verified that the error when running indexWebScg.fcgi was occurring due to the lack of modules installed in your vritualEnv, I installed the necessary modules , however I noticed that one of the modules of your application is the "zbar" this module is not compatible with our shared plans because it requires a server-level library called libzbar which is not standard on our shared servers. "

My question is, if everything I need to use on the system is installed inside the virtualenv and upload all of this simultaneously to the server, why would I need to install only this library at the root level of the server? Did I do the wrong installation of the "pyzbar" library in my virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

To run zbar library you need to install on running os or on any server.
sudo apt-get install libzbar0

pyzbar uses this library to decide qr and barcode.

In virtual environment the pyzbar works but the connection to libzbar0 breaks when you Port this to server.

To make this work you have to install libzbar0 on your server.